# localization xcode 8 не работает

Tags: ios, xcode

IOS проект, ставлю несколько локализаций, запускаю(пробывал и на симуляторе и на устройстве), в любом случае отображается base язык. в превью в assistant Mode, все меняется правильно, clean project пробовал, переустанавливать приложение пробовал.

Для примера создавал новые проекты, там все работает. 
Скорее всего ошибка в том, что игрался с локализацией и потом удалил не все настройки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Это распространенная проблема. Поищите ваш текст через поиск в Xcode. Скорее всего он принадлежит неверному идентификатору объекта.

Вообще я рекомендую делать локализацию через код, это самый надежный и предсказуемый путь, например:

Objective C

```
self.lbl_allow_comments.text = NSLocalizedString(@"allow_comments", @"Some Example text");
```

Swift

```
self.lbl_allow_comments.text = NSLocalizedString("allow_comments", comment: "Some Example text")
```

Или почитать вот эту статью: ["Удобная локализация iOS приложений в Interface Builder"](https://habrahabr.ru/post/325810/) и сделать как там описано.